# Dúvidas com método post no angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Olá, estou tentando fazer um método POST que me retorna um objeto 'Usuário'.

No meu BackEnd tenho o seguinte código:

```
 //Add um Usuarios
 public Usuarios Post([FromBody]Usuarios usuario)
 {
     return _usuariosServices.Adicionar(usuario);
 }
```

Ou seja, me retorna um objeto 'Usuário'.

No angular eu faço a chamada desse método e a requisição chega no BackEnd, porém não consigo jogar o retorno em uma variável do angular...

Meu método do Angular ta da seguinte forma...

```
CriandoUsuario(usuario: UsuariosModel){
  let headers = new Headers();
  headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json')

  this.http.post(`${API}` + 'Usuarios'
  , JSON.stringify(usuario)
  , { headers: headers })
  . subscribe(() => {});
 }
```

Pelo que entendo, é necessário fazer algo dentro do 'Subscribe', porém não sei o que é esse algo...
Agradeço desde já...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Voce esta complicando desnecessariamente. Depois so dar o subscribe no retorno da função.

```
httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type':  'application/json'      
})

constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {         
}


criarUsuario(usuario: UsuariosModel){
  return this.httpClient.post(`${API}Usuarios`, user, this.httpOptions)
}
```